# construct a new hash with different keys

Tags: ruby

```
hash = { 
  "key1_sub1" => [0, 1, 2], 
  "key2_sub2" => [1, 12], 
  "key3_sub1" => [4, 5, 6] 
}
```

is there a one liner will return me a new hash

it find the hash value matching the key pattern "_sub1" in the original hash, construct the new key by removing "_sub1"

```
new_hash = { "key1" => [0, 1, 2], "key3" => [4, 5, 6] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.each_with_object({}){|(k, v), h| h[k.sub(/_sub1/, '')] = v if k[/_sub1/]}
```

Comment: using the pattern "_sub1", i only want to get 2 matches, "key1_sub1" and "key2_sub1",  i don't want "key2_sub2".   the final result should be { "key1" => [0, 1, 2], "key3" => [4, 5, 6] }  not {"key1"=>[0, 1, 2], "key2_sub2"=>[1, 12], "key3"=>[4, 5, 6]}

Comment: I'm removing mine... Yours is better, and I ripped off most of it.  :-)  +1 for the good answer.

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic and readable without all the extraneous boilerplate of `each_with_object`: `Hash[ hash.map {|k, v| [k.sub(/.+_sub1$/, ''), v] if k =~ /.+_sub1$/} ]` — it will also work in Ruby 1.8.7 and I'd guess it will be faster in most Rubies since it requires fewer explicit message sends, though I haven't benchmarked.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`new_hash = Hash[*hash.keys.map{ |x| x.gusb /_sub\d$/, '' }.zip(hash.values)]`